# How would I set the column width of a GraphicsRow?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, grid-layouts

I would like to place a sphere next to a table of text in a `GraphicsRow`.  I am not using a `GraphicsGrid` because I only need one row.

My text table is truncated by the `GraphicRow`.  I only see a few columns of my table of text.

```
borderSeg = {{-40, -120},{10,-80}};
linkSeg = {{-20, -120},{-30,-100}};


borderGCVector = { (Sin[borderSeg[[1,1]]° - borderSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°+borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Cos[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°- borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])-
                       (Sin[borderSeg[[1,1]]° + borderSeg[[2,1]]°] Cos[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°+borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Sin[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°- borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2]),
                       (Sin[borderSeg[[1,1]]° - borderSeg[[2,1]]°] Cos[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°+borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Cos[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°- borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])+
                       ( Sin[borderSeg[[1,1]]° + borderSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°+borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Sin[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°- borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2]),
                        (Cos[borderSeg[[1,1]]°] Cos[borderSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(borderSeg[[1,2]]°- borderSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])};

linkGCVector = { (Sin[linkSeg[[1,1]]° - linkSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°+linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Cos[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°- linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])-
                       (Sin[linkSeg[[1,1]]° + linkSeg[[2,1]]°] Cos[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°+linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Sin[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°- linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2]),
                       (Sin[linkSeg[[1,1]]° - linkSeg[[2,1]]°] Cos[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°+linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Cos[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°- linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])+
                        (Sin[linkSeg[[1,1]]° + linkSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°+linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2] Sin[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°- linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2]),
                        (Cos[linkSeg[[1,1]]°] Cos[linkSeg[[2,1]]°] Sin[(linkSeg[[1,2]]°- linkSeg[[2,2]]°)/2])};

CGVectors = {borderGCVector, linkGCVector};
GraphicsRow[
        {
             (* Simple graphic to show cross products *)
             Graphics3D[ {{Opacity[0.05],Sphere[{0,0,0}]},
                          {Dashed, Line[{{0,0,0},{1,0,0}}]},
                          {Dashed, Line[{{0,0,0},{0,1,0}}]},
                          {Dashed, Line[{{0,0,0},{0,0,1}}]},
                          Arrow[{{1,0,0},{1.3,0,0}}],
                           Arrow[{{0,1,0},{0,1.3,0}}],
                           Arrow[{{0,0,1},{0,0,1.3}}],
                          Text[Style["x",Blue, Italic,12],{1.4,0,0}],
                          Text[Style["y",Blue, Italic,12],{0,1.4,0}],
                          Text[Style["z",Blue, Italic,12],{0,0,1.4}],
                         Arrow[{{0,0,0},#}]& /@ CGVectors},Boxed->False],
             (* Table of values computed in Mathematica and values computed by C# methods *)
             Text[Grid[ {{"","Border Normal", "Link Normal","Border Normal", "Link Normal"},
                         {"", "Mathematica", "Mathematica", "C#", "C#"},
                         {"x", N[borderGCVector[[1]]], N[linkGCVector[[1]]],"0.738606","-0.115201"},
                         {"y", N[borderGCVector[[2]]], N[linkGCVector[[2]]],"-0.043412","-0.183489"},
                         {"z", N[borderGCVector[[3]]], N[linkGCVector[[3]]],"-0.258022",""}},
                          ItemSize->12
                         Frame->All, FrameStyle->LightGray, ItemStyle->{{1->{FontSlant->Italic}},{1->{FontFamily->"Arial",FontSize->9}}}]]
        }
    ]
```

Is there a way to set the size of a column in a GraphicRow?

Comment: Suggestion: use `Grid` and (if necessary) option `ItemSize` even though you have only one row of two items.

Comment: Please provide definitions for `borderGCVector` and `linkGCVector`. Your code doesn't run without them.

Comment: Vector definitions have been added.

Comment: In the Grid, is there a way to specify that the two items are on a single row instead of a vertical column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using [`GraphicsRow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsRow.html), you can manipulate the size of an element by using spanning elements next to it.

```
GraphicsRow[{Graphics3D[...],Text[Grid[...]], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}]
```

Alternatively, as m_goldberg suggests above, use [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)and double curly brackets `{{item1, item2}}` or a simple [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html)

**EDIT**

Actually, there is a typo in your code in the text table -- missing comma after `ItemSize->12`. If you insert it, the table gets bigger and you have to add few more spanning elements, but then the overall graphics size is limiting you, so you have to adjust it by using `ImageSize -> {700, 100}`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch!  Used Grid with double braces - did the trick